# Typing a function based on the argument value

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have the following JS function:

```
function extractProperty(propName) {
    return x => x[propName];
}
```

Can I type `extractProperty` s.t. by Typescript's type inference I get the following:

```
const x = { first: 1, second: "two" };
const y = { first: [1], second: 2 };
// or any other object having first and second

const a1 = extractProperty("first")(x); // a1 should be of type number
const a2 = extractProperty("second")(x); // a2 should be string
const a3 = extractProperty("first")(y); // a3 should be number[]
const a4 = extractProperty("second")(y); // a4 should be number

const getFirst = extractProperty("first");
// getFirst should be <T> (t: T) => T["first"]

const getSecond = extractProperty("second");
// getSecond should be <T> (t: T) => T["second"]
```

If rather than a parameter `propName`, I had a fixed property name, I could probably do the following:

```
function extractPropertyFirst ():
<TFirst> (x: { first: TFirst }) => TFirst
```

or, slightly more in the direction of what I want to achieve,

```
function extractPropertyFirst ():
<T> (x: T) => T["first"]
```

Yet how can I make typescript take the argument of the function as the property name?

I have played around with the following approach, yet without success:

```
function getProperty<K> (propName: K):
<TProp> (t: { [K]: TProp }) => TProp {
    return x => x[propName];
}
```

Typescript does not accept a general `K` as the indexing type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `getProperty` work by using `{[Key in K]: TProp}`, or equivalently, `Record<K, TProp>` for the type of `t`, and adding an `K extends PropertyKey` constraint:

```
function extractProperty<K extends PropertyKey>( propName: K):
  <TProp>(t: Record<K, TProp>) => TProp {
    return (x) => x[propName];
  }

const a1 = extractProperty("first")(x);
// type: number

const a2 = extractProperty("second")(x)
// type: string

const a3 = extractProperty("first")(y);
// type: number[]

const a4 = extractProperty("second")(y);
// type: number
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB5QE4ENoAUNwAOyGUAngDwDSK6yYAJgM6L5EnlXJkB8AFIkIFCAOSwBbZAC5EVAJRSAUIkQUAKm0L8oMgErIIcDA2oAaRBuE85iALw8LmxAG9lKxBmRQQGJH1Q29oioANpCRGKSALoA3G4AvoqKhmBMUMF2LojAMBhpMgCM5kwGCAwyAERQAO5wFYjxcSlpiGSZztm5+YghBVHFpYwyAEwNcQD044hGiFhgbXBQABYk0wBGAFYG6UtYAG4wYADmnXnpcwyIJSkMSc3nBZlomDhQmhxkfBU5ZxVy-nIYohJrNHkwlnAQAAbS5rZDTYCIcjERBgEDiOEYRQg9wAPQA-HcEC0sKNbLQXnhhB8vtcyn8AUCQaSrhDobD4WkMIcjtipnjCcliecAMxPdDYKnsUifb5dKAMsiA4FTLBi8GQmGIOGo9GYkJRPnuRAEompc4AFnFlLe1JltMGDEVyuZVo17O18LRGJIRoFZpaRy8ADF5dbJbbpeQvj80n8JlMg1BQ2dWZqOao1A4+DoLIEHGoQnLfoahebEEmAMqO8Ovd72ip0xjxo1VmvurU69TZ3NqfMWItNp2l+5I5Atcltm6Mv0qU1AA)

Comment: Thank you. That was quick! I did not know about `PropertyKey` until now.

Comment: Sorry, still a question: Why does `Record<K, TProp>` work, but `{ [K]: TProp }` does not?

Comment: The second type declares an object with a computed property `K`, where `K` is a value rather than a type. Using the value instead (i.e. `{[propName]: TProp}`) won't work either as computed property key expressions cannot have generic types.